# Scrapy error show when there are no data to scrape for an object

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I keep getting the error "'NoneType' object is not subscriptable" when I run my Scrapy code. I understand that the object value is None, but how to skip that and instruct Scrapy to record this object as an empty one?

Here are the method

```
def parse_country(self, response):
    try:

        item = response.meta['item']
        link_id = response.meta['link_id']
        place_data = json.loads(response.body)
        
        place_country = place_data[0][0][0]

        item['place_country'] = place_country

        yield item
    
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

The error only show when there are no data to scrape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many tests, here are the code that works for me

```
def parse_images(self, response):
    try:
                   
        link_id = response.meta['link_id']
        place_data = json.loads(response.body)
        item = response.meta['item']
        
        try: 
            place_country = place_data[0][0][0]
        except:
            place_country = ''

        yield {
            'link_id': link_id,
            'place_country': place_country
        }
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Try/except` is useful to catch errors or bugs.
I would suggest an `if/else` solution.

Something like that could work for you:

```
def parse_country(self, response):
    item = response.meta['item']
    link_id = response.meta['link_id']
    place_data = json.loads(response.body)                    
                 
    if place_data[0][0][0] is not None:
         place_country = place_data[0][0][0]
         item['place_country'] = place_country
    else
         item['place_country'] = 'No Country found'
```

Comment: It still gives the same error after using if/else.

Comment: what's the possible 'NoneType' element  ?

Comment: It shall be item['place_country'] = place_country

Comment: if `response.body` is empty, you shoud get `place_data[0][0][0] = None`. So you can test `place_data[0][0][0]` in your `if/else` condition. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the use of `try` block as a control statement is not a good practice.

When you write
`place_data[0][0][0]` it means that you are looking for multi-level nested list. The solution is to check for `None` and length at each level. If any of these items are `None` you will have this error.

The solution is to check for all these values. You can do it one if statement like this

```
if place_data and len(place_data) > 0 \
         and place_data[0] and len(place_data[0]) > 0 \
         and place_data[0][0] and len(place_data[0][0]) \
         and place_data[0][0][0]:
    item['place_country'] = place_data[0][0][0]
else:
     item['place_country'] = None
```

Or you could break it down into multiple, nested `if` statements for better readability.

Side note # 1: Use of `meta` is not recommended in the newer version of scrapy. Use `cb_kwargs` instead. [See the docs](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.cb_kwargs).

Side Note # 2: You can directly get `json` by calling `response.json()`

Comment: Thanks for your anser and the 2 notes. I added below the code that works for me after running many blind tests.
For note 2: You means not to use json.loads(response.body) ?